# How to get SQL from Django QuerySet with filter parameters properly quoted?

Tags: django

```
MyModel.objects.filter(name="my name", date__lte=datetime.now()).query
```

Outputs:

```
SELECT "mymodel"."id", "mymodel"."name", "mymodel"."date" 
FROM "mymodel" 
WHERE ("mymodel"."name" = my name AND "mymodel"."date" <= 2016-02-24 20:24:00.456974+00:00)
```

Which is not a valid SQL (filter parameters are unquoted).

How can I get the exact SQL that will be executed, which is:

```
SELECT "mymodel"."id", "mymodel"."name", "mymodel"."date" 
FROM "mymodel" 
WHERE ("mymodel"."name" = 'my name' AND "mymodel"."date" <= '2016-02-24 20:24:00.456974+00:00'::timestamptz)
```

Answer (score 12):

This isn't fully answering it, but for my purposes I wanted to be able to rerun the query as raw sql. I was able to get sql and params using:

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(name="my name", date__lte=datetime.now())
sql, sql_params = queryset.query.get_compiler(using=queryset.db).as_sql()
```

Then I could use these values to rerun the query as raw:

```
MyModel.objects.raw(sql, sql_params)
```

Comment: Dude you saved me hours of torture, I did not know about the get_compiler method, i was `queryset.query.__str__()` and going to the dark side of regex since Django was not escaping the parameters when you invoice str like that

Comment: I don't know from which Django version, but it could be more simplified to `queryset.query.sql_with_params()`